# Auto roll down windows Honda?

Tags: honda, power-windows, fob

So I put my keys in my pocket and occasionally it rolls down the windows on my Honda ridge line with nothing else in my pocket?

Apparently there is no way to disable this feature.  Could I get a new key fob or something or maybe a fuse to disable this feature?  Until it rains and this happens it is not a big deal but it sure is annoying.

Comment: Is there a button on the key that is being pressed?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: This video shows how to do it.  It seems strange that you have to use the key in a lock to close the windows -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nE3XvLc2vHk

Answer (score 0):

Many cars include features that can be enabled or disabled by the dealer who has the special programming equipment.  For example, I have a Mini Cooper and there are several functions that can be attached to the door unlock button on the FOB.    I believe your Honda is similar.

Unfortunately I don't think this is anything that can be self-enabled or disabled but I believe the dealer can do it for you.  You may want to visit your dealer and ask about this feature and what it might take to turn it off.

You indicated that the dealer says "no" there is no way to disable this feature.  Perhaps a key FOB case that protects the button while it's in your pocket then?

Comment: I called the dealer unfortunately this is a no

Answer (score -1):

**English translation**:

What happens is that the window controls are failing, they are stuck, maintenance can be done, you only remove it with a flat screwdriver, disconnect it and if it is better, change the part.

**Original Text**:

Lo que pasa es que esta fallando los controles de las ventanas se quedaron pegados se puede dar mantenimiento solo lo quitas con un desarmador plano desconectas y si es mejor cambias la pieza

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair! StackExchage is an English only site (with noted exceptions). I've used Google Translate to get as close to your answer as I'm able to. In the future, please answer using English.